# ArrayList of Objects help java

Tags: arraylist

Ok, so I have an assignment for my computer class that is pretty simple (its supposed to show transversing through arrays and stuff). I had to create a version with arrays and a version with arrayLists so in the tester class I have some static methods, but when I use the arrayList and I try to call a method from the class that the object is from (its a getter method) all I get is an error message that says it can't be found.

Here is a shortened version of my code:

import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public class testCandidate2
{

```
public static int getTotal(ArrayList election)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int b = 0; b <election.size(); b++)
          total += election.getNumVotes();
    return total;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int totalVotes;
    List <Candidate> election = new ArrayList<Candidate>(5);
    election.add() = new Candidate(5000, "John Smith");

    totalVotes = getTotal(election);

}
```

}

public class Candidate
{

```
private String name;
private int numVotes;

Candidate(int nv, String n)
{
    name = n;
    numVotes = nv;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public int getNumVotes()
{
    return numVotes;
}

public String toString()
{
    return name + " recieved " + numVotes + " votes.";
}
```

}

Comment: try replacing this line  election.add() = new Candidate(5000, "John Smith"); with  election.add(new Candidate(5000, "John Smith"));

Comment: thanks I'm sure that's better but I still get an error message on "total += election.getNumVotes();" I have also tried "total += election.get(b).getNumVotes();" and I sstill get the same error message "cannot find symbol - method getNumVotes()"

Comment: You may find useful my tutorial on [Internal life of ArrayList](http://volodial.blogspot.com/2013/07/internal-life-of-arraylist-in-java.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
import java.util.*;
//import java.util.List;

public class testCandidate2 {

public static int getTotal(ArrayList election)
{
    int total = 0;
    for(int b = 0; b <election.size(); b++)
         {
         Candidate ele = (Candidate) election.get(b);
       //  System.out.println(ele.getNumVotes());
         total += ele.getNumVotes();
         //System.out.println(o.getNumVotes());
    }
         //System.out.println( (Candidate) (election.get(b).getNumVotes());
          //.getNumVotes();
    return total;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int totalVotes;
    ArrayList <Candidate> election = new ArrayList<Candidate>(5);
    election.add(new Candidate(5000, "John Smith"));

    totalVotes = getTotal(election);
    System.out.println(totalVotes);
}
}
```